# Uniqueness field using Scope of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rspec, factory-bot

I want to insure that an items name is unique within an organization. So I've used the "validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: [:organization]" within Item. This unfortunetely didn't work.

Error (edited):

```
>   1) Item 
>      Failure/Error: @item_1 = create(:item, :item_category => @item_cat_1)
>      
>      NoMethodError:
>        undefined method `organization_id' for #<Item:0x00000002565840>
```

models:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item_category
  has_one :organization, through: :item_category
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: [:organization]
end

class ItemCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items
    belongs_to :organization
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_categories
  has_many :items, :through => item_categories
end
```

In theory, as I did above may I use the item's, item_category association (belongs_to :item_category) for the organization_id?

If the above isn't possible. I guess I could have an organization_id in the item and the item_category. But then how could we validate that a item.organization_id be always equal to an item_category.organization_id (its association)

Comment: Are your business requirements such that all Items must have unique names across an entire Organization? Would duplicate names in different ItemCategories be ok?

Comment: All items must have unique names across an entire organization. Also since an item_category belongs_to an organization you should not have duplicate item names in the scope of an organization. Hope that clarifies things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is okay to not include the organization_id inside an item?

Yes, not include because the column organization_id will be redundant.

For complex validation, we usually use customized one to validate, here is my example, you may correct it:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item_category
  has_one :organization, through: :item_category
  # validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: [:organization]
  validate :check_uniqueness_of_name

  def check_uniqueness_of_name
    if Organization.includes(item_categories: :items).where.not(items: {id: self.id}).where(items: {name: self.name}).count > 0
      errors.add(:name, 'name was duplidated')
    end
  end
end
```